# Can curve live off the embedding diagram in general relatiity?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

The embedding diagram is well known for its qualitative representation of how the stress energy tensor curve the spacetime. We can construct a map from a general spherical metric to a cylindrical metric if we want to construct such diagrams.

Now, my confusion is if there exist curves out of the surface.
It seems to me that curves can indeed exist out of the diagrams. Since they are only a 3D representation of the curvature of the spacetime, a curve living out of the surface does not means that it lives out the spacetime. Now, even so this line of thought seems right to me, i am not 100% of this!

[image]

[http://www1.kcn.ne.jp/~h-uchii/embed.diag.html](http://www1.kcn.ne.jp/%7Eh-uchii/embed.diag.html)

Comment: There's this Nash embedding theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorems

Answer (score 1):

The embedding diagram is a well-known but a very misleading representation of how matter curves space and time. This kind of visualization works with extrinsic curvature in 3D, without considering time, whereas the space-time curvature is a strictly intrinsic property. There is no ambient space at all. Compare your pictures with the animation: [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://youtu.be/wrwgIjBUYVc). It the best visualization of gravitation I have seen as yet.